# Shell Programming Question with Loops, Until and While

Tags: shell-script

I need a solution for the below:

> Write a shell program to print the numbers in the following format:
>   *Use* *While* or *Until* loop for the following program

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
6 7 8 9
```

My written script is using a *until loop*. Kindly correct where I have made a mistake:

```
#!/bin/bash

w=1
until [ $w -le 9 ] ; do
    until [ $w -eq 4 ] ; do
        w=`expr $w + 1`
        echo “$w”
    done
    echo “$w”
done
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: There are more than enough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `bash` you don't need two loops for that, one + brace expansion is enough:

```
i=0; width=4; max=9
until [ $((i++)) -ge $((max-width+1)) ]; do
    eval echo {$i..$((i+width-1))}
done
```

Should work for any widths > 0, and starting points (including negative values).

If you really like to use two loops just rewrite inner line with brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
width=4
max=9

decr=$(($width-1))
for w in $(seq $(($max-$decr)))
do
    seq -s' ' $w $(($w+$decr))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this be written without width and max variables using my simple nested loop ?

As below :-

```
w=1
until [ $w -le 9 ] ; do
    until [ $w -eq 4 ] ; do
        w=`expr $w + 1`
        echo “$w”
    done
    echo “$w”
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script will not even enter the first loop as `$w` is less than 9 from the start. You probably want `-gt` rather than `-lt` there, and we really only want this loop to run until `$w` is bigger than 6 (6 lines of output):

```
w=1

until (( w > 6 )); do
    ...

    w=$(( w + 1 ))
done
```

In the inner loop, you'd like to output a row of four numbers.  The numbers should go from `$w` to `$w` plus 3.

```
x=$w

until (( x > w + 3 )); do
    ...
    x=$(( x + 1 ))
done
```

What should happen in there? Well, `$x` should be outputted without any newline. So,

```
printf '%d ' "$x"
```

The neline can be added after the inner loop with `echo`.

This leaves us with

```
w=1

until (( w > 6 )); do
    x=$w

    until (( x > w + 3 )); do
        printf '%d ' "$x"
        x=$(( x + 1 ))
    done
    echo

    w=$(( w + 1 ))
done
```

---

This is just for fun:

With `bash`:

```
n=123456789
for i in ${!BASH_VERSINFO[@]}; do 
  { while read -n 1; do printf '%c ' $REPLY; done; echo; } <<<"${n:$i:4}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
b=1
while [ $b -le 6 ]
do
echo -n $b `expr $b + 1` `expr $b + 2` `expr $b + 3`
echo
b=`expr $b +1`
done
```

Comment: It does answer the "print the numbers in the following format", but does not answer "kindly correct where I have made a mistake". Welcome to the site, Alex! New users posts, and answers to old questions get extra attention (review) so that you can learn how the site works. Explaining your code, and addressing all of the Question can help make great Answers.